# Using Winform C# , delete the folder the exe exists in

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an winform exe which removes an application and the required folder the application has. But I want to delete the winform root folder as well. So is there a method to do so as I am informed its not possible to delete the folder with the exe running inside it. So is there any TEMP path or something similar where I can copy the uninstaller so it removes the setup root folder as well as itself get's deleted after the process is completed.

Thanks

Comment: `is there any TEMP path` Um, yes? [`Path.GetTempPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The application you're removing should have an uninstaller, and that should be sued. Or the user should shutdown the removed application before running yours. As is now, it seems that you are doing something that is not intended by the user, removing one of the apps currently in use. Explain why your actions are legit.

Comment: @RemusRusanu  Actually I made an application with performs some function. Now I wanted to have a uninstaller for that. So I programmed both installer and uninstaller in same exe. So I was stuck at this part while removing the files. Visual Vincent answer helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run an invisible instance of CMD to do the deleting for you:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", 
    String.Format("/k {0} & {1} & {2}", 
        "timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL",
        "rmdir /s /q \"" + Application.StartupPath + "\"",
        "exit"
    )
);

psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process.Start(psi);
```

Execute the above code when your application is about to close, and it'll remove the directory it's located in.

The commands used:

```
timeout /T x /NOBREAK >NUL
    - Wait for a certain amount of time.
        /T x     - Wait for x seconds.
        /NOBREAK - Specifies that it shouldn't be interrupted by pressing Space or Enter.
        >NUL     - Don't output any messages to the console.

rmdir /s /q <path>
    - Removes the directory <path>.
        /s - Remove subfiles and subdirectories.
        /q - Don't ask for confirmation.

exit
    - Closes the CMD instance
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Be ***really*** careful when using this as it will remove the entire directory, no matter what's in it!

Comment: @AnkurRai : I'm glad I could help! Good luck with your project!